# I want to show details of any record using generic repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

the Irepository class in which interface have

```
void  details(int id);
```

the code for repository class is :

```
public void details(int id) {
    T st = db.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

and the home controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult details(int id)
{
    return View(re.details(id));
}
```

it is giving me the error of cannot convert from void to object 
if do this in home controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult details(int id)
{
    var abc = re.details(id);
    return View(abc);
}
```

Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable `AutoText1`

Answer (score 0):

the logic of having the details function to return void isn`t understandable for me and to solve that

as refereed by the exception you need to have a return type and return the T object from the repository to the api then pass the object to the view.

plus the view model should expect to receive an object of any type then handle showing the details maybe dynamically based on the object properties

Comment: thanks for your help .it was a silly mistake i was doing